# What is the best way to increase the performance of this code?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to fetch the data from multiple related tables with pagination in C#.

The performance of the below code is slow by using the multiple include statements as I need to fetch the related data. What is the best optimization I can do here?

Note that I have the primary key column of type `uniqueidentifier`.

```
var data = await dbcontext.CandidateForm
                          .Include(candidate => candidate.PersonalDetail)
                          .Include(candidate => candidate.AcademicQualifications)
                          .Include(candidate => candidate.TeachingExperiences)
                          .Include(candidate => candidate.CandidateHigherQualification)
                          .Where(x => x.PostCategory == PostName)
                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
                          .Skip((filter.PageNumber - 1) * filter.PageSize)
                          .Take(filter.PageSize)
                          .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: In your database (unclear, what RDBMS it is you're using), ensure that proper indexing is in place. For SQL Server - make sure, the foreign key columns of those tables involved are indexed, ensure you have an index on `PostCategory` (since you're limiting your query based on that column) and on `CreatedDate` (since you're sorting on it) etc.

Answer (score 1):

first make a query that finds PostCategoryId and then

```
.Where(x => x.PostCategoryId == PostId)
```

search base on integer is more faster than string
next if you can select specific columns that you need

```
.ToListAsync();
```

alone, selects all columns in table, that is heavy compared to one or more columns.
next, instead of includes its better you select exactly what you want from that tables